# Are $i,j,k$ and $\hat{e}_x ,\hat{e}_y, \hat{e}_z $ equivalent?

Tags: vectors

Are $i,j,k$ and $\hat{e}_x ,\hat{e}_y, \hat{e}_z $ are equivalent?

If i am given a question for a vector field which is written in $\hat{e}_x ,\hat{e}_y, \hat{e}_z $ from and i give the answer in $i,j,k$ would it be correct.

Comment: They are different notations for the standard (orthonormal) basis in $\mathbb R^3$